# ValueError: Input and filter shapes must be int or symbolic in Conv2D node

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, coreml

I was trying to convert my .pb file to a CoreML model using `tfcoreml` (with the script below) when I got this error: `ValueError: Input and filter shapes must be int or symbolic in Conv2D node detector/darknet-53/Conv/Conv2D`. How would I resolve this error and convert my model to CoreML successfully?

I opened up my .pb model with Netron and found the layer in question:

[image: Netron Graph]

Here is the conversion script I am using:

```
import tfcoreml

tfcoreml.convert(tf_model_path='model.pb',
                 mlmodel_path='model.mlmodel',
                 output_feature_names=['output_boxes'],  # name of the output op
                 input_name_shape_dict={'inputs': [None, 416, 416, 3]},  # map from the placeholder op in the graph to shape (can have -1s)
                 minimum_ios_deployment_target='13')
```

From what I can gather it seems to me that I need to change the input types of all `Conv2D` nodes to get this to work. But I am not an expert by any means so I could be wrong. Is there a way I can fix this model to convert successfully by using a Python script, and if so what would it look like?

**EDIT:** After changing the `None` in the `input_name_shape_dict` I got a different error. This one says: `ValueError: Incompatible dimension 3 in Sub operation detector/darknet-53/Conv/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm/Sub`. So I opened up Netron once again I took a look. Here is what I got, any idea how to fix it?

[image: Netron Graph 2]

It seems the script got past the previous error just to get stuck on the next layer. Is my .pb completely useless or does just need to be fixed in some places?

Answer (score 0):

Try 1 instead of `None` in the `input_name_shape_dict`.